# Generic implementation of a factory for classes of different types

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We are being provided a set of Entity and Consumer classes. Calling the XConsumer returns an XEntity, while calling the YConsumer returns an YEntity and so on. The APIs for the Consumer classes are identical taking arguments of same type. The Consumer and Entity classes do not inherit from a base class nor implement an Interface. What I would like to achieve is to generically call a factory that returns a desired Entity of a particular type. My current implementation looks like so:

```
static class Factory<TConsumer> where TConsumer : new()
{
 static dynamic Consume(Document document, out List<Error> errors)
 {
   // Common code before calling any consumer goes here
   Stream stream = document.Stream;

   dynamic consumer = new TConsumer();
   return consumer.Consume(stream, out errors);
 }
}
```

My calling code looks like so

```
XEntity entity = Factory<XConsumer>.Consume(document, out errors);
```

Note I’m only in charge of the Factory class and the calling code and not allowed to modify the Entity and Consumer classed. Is there a way to make this better, preferably without using dynamic?

Comment: Your factory doesn't look like a factory, rather like something that combines a factory with a service - you not only create an instance but also call a method on it and instead of returning the instance you return the result of a method called on it. This seem to violate the SRP. Also, if your `TConsumer` is `new()` then why do you need the `Activator` if you can `new` the `TConsumer`?

Comment: I know this solution is not optimal. Why you suggesting?

Comment: Consumer can be of different types. Initially I was passing in a lambda in to the Consume method, like so () => new XConsumer(). But landed on activator instead and it made the API simpler

Comment: I think Wiktor's point is that rather than doing `dynamic consumer = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TConsumer));` you can just do `TConsumer consumer = new TConsumer();` because you have the constraint `TConsumer : new()`. Thus, no dynamic or reflection, just use of generics as intended.

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated the code to dynamic consumer = new TConsume(); which I do prefer over using Activator. However I still need to use dynamic. Using TConsumer for declaration produces the following error "TConsumer' does not contain a definition for 'Consume' and no extension method 'Consume' accepting a first argument of type 'TConsumer' could be found"

Comment: `I want code that is simple and easy to understand.` I think you have that. Fyi, `new T()` is compiled to `Activator.CreateInstance` (but it looks nicer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you need to get the entity classes changed so that they both implement an interface, eg IEntity. The factory should select the consumer based on some criteria, rather than knowing which consumer you want to use. You can base this decision on the required wntiry return type.

Eg:

```
// you don't necessarily need this interface but it allows a meaningful
// constraint if you apply it to your 'entity' classes. If you can't apply
// this interface to the entity classes then remove the constraints below
public interface IEntity
{
    // things it does
}

public class XEntity : IEntity
{
}

public class YEntity : IEntity
{
}

public interface IConsumer<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity // remove constraint if required
{
    TEntity Consume(Stream stream, out List<Error> errors);
}

public class XConsumer : IConsumer<XEntity>
{
    public XEntity Consume(Stream stream, out List<Error> errors);
    {
        // something
    }
}

public class YConsumer : IConsumer<YEntity>
{
    public YEntity Consume(Stream stream, out List<Error> errors);
    {
        // something
    }
}

public static class ConsumerFactory
{
    // this will now create a consumer instance based on the entity type
    public static IConsumer<TEntity> Create<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity // remove constraint if required
    {
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(XEntity))
            return new XConsumer;
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(YEntity))
            return new YConsumer;
        throw new Exception("Unsupported type");
    }
    public static TEntity Consume<TEntity>(Stream stream, out List<Error> errors) where TEntity : IEntity // remove constraint if required
    {
        return Create<TEntity>().Consume(stream, out errors);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
XEntity x = ConsumerFactory.Consume<XEntity>(document, out errors);
YEntity y = ConsumerFactory.Consume<YEntity>(document, out errors);
```

Comment: This won’t work. Your interface declaration is expecting a return type of XEntity which is not correct. It should be a generic type entity

Comment: Also refer to my response to Zohar

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive response Steve, but as I already mentioned I’ve thought about this. This solution doesn’t provides any benefit due to large number of Entity and a consumer classes, just more code to write and maintain

Comment: Ok, this does actually answer your question as you wanted to create the entity without using dynamic. This also means that only the factory needs to know which consumer matches each entity, rather than the developer needing to know. There would be other ways to determine which consumer to use, such as reflection. Is that what you want? The code to automatically select the consumer via reflection?

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid reflection is to use the [Adapter pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Basically, what you do is create an `interface` that contains the common methods and properties of your `consumer` classes, and create a wrapper class for each `consumer` that implements this interface.

This way you can implement your method without using `dynamic` or `reflection`, and keep it type safe.

The downside is, of course, you are going to have to write (and maintain) a lot more code than what you currently have.

Comment: Though about this already but I don’t see this a pragmatic solution.thanks for response

Comment: I didn't say it's pragmatic... I'm not a big fan of design patterns myself. A lot of them seems to me like a waste of time - just like in this case -
 you have to write and maintain much more code then you would with another solution that actually gets the job done.  My top 3 principles for development are KISS, DRY, and Don`t Reinvent the wheel. I find that a lot of design patters don't let you KISS or DRY.

Comment: I want code that is simple and easy to understand. I have indefinite number of consumers and entities. The adapter pattern is not really an option. I’m not arguing, you are right it is much more added code for no benefit

Answer (score 0):

No reflection is not what I want. I’m marking your response as answer but I’m going to stick with my own implementation. Originally I thought I post this question in case I missed   something